# Using period symbol after django-admin startproject <projectname>

Tags: python, django

I have been following two different tutorials about the Django framework and in one of the frameworks, I entered the following commands: django-admin startproject mysite .
In this command, the author specifically asked to enter a period after the command. The following pic is the structure of the folder created:https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3Cab.png

In the second tutorial which is on the official Django website, I used the following command:
django-admin startproject mysite
In this command, I did not use a period in the end and the folder structure is as follows:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/aI50z.png.

You can clearly see from both the images that one has a single mysite folder with 4 other .py modules inside it, whereas in the other there is another mysite folder inside the mysite folder.

Can anyone please explain why there is this difference and which is better for use?

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with the directory structures you can read
`Django for Beginners by William S Vincent`.

```
└── config
    ├── config
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── asgi.py
    │   ├── settings.py
    │   ├── urls.py
    │   └── wsgi.py
    └── manage.py
```

See how it creates a new directory config and then within it a manage.py file and a config directory? That feels redundant to me since we already created and navigated into a django directory on our Desktop. By running django-admin startproject config . with the period at the end–which says, install in the current directory–the result is instead this

```
├── config
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── asgi.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
└── manage.py
```

All methods are correct though

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. The first configuration that feels redundant is mentioned on the official website of Django :)

Answer (score 0):

Not a Django pro by any means, by I keep finding that I like to 1) create a work directory for a project, 2) create a venv virtual environment in the work directory, 3) activate the virtual environment then run `startproject` without the dot.

This means that the `env` directory for the virtual environment lives *outside* the Django project directory, which is handy because I can develop on my laptop, push the Django project directory to a git repo, then clone the repo on a server with a totally different virtual environment to deploy.

Examples I've seen and worked through using `startproject .` wind up with the venv directory *inside* the Django project directory, which gets messy when developing and deploying on different machines.